# How to pass RTSP stream to WebRTC in Android

Tags: java, webrtc, rtsp

Currently, we are developing an Android app in which we need to transfer the RTSP stream to WebRTC. The RTSP stream will come to the app through Wifi network and we need to pass the stream to WebRTC. As per our understanding, WebRTC will support only the streams from built in camera, screen-sharing and I420 yuv formatted video files.

Is there any way to transfer the RTSP stream to WebRTC from the Android code?

Comment: hey prijesh,you found solution.